# TabActivity to FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity, android-fragmentactivity

I have been searching answer but no where to be found. Seem that this is really new.
Google says TabActivity is deprecated and should use FragmentActivity.

Previously I have all the activities to be switched in tabHost.

Now if I want to switch to FragmentActivity

1. Do I have to changed all my extends Activity class to extends Fragment class (or what is the exact class name)?
2. Can I just use back my Activity classes to be switched in TabHost instead of .. Fragment?
3. Is there any good, simple and straight to point tutorial on this?

It is very late night now and I am sure I have more questions.. have been figuring whole day.
I wonder why Google making developer life harder? Looks at how iOS tab is implemented so easily. Now I begin to understand why all the apps come out in iOS first instead of Android.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you have to make all your activities to extend Fragment or FragmentActivity.
2. Yes, you can keep all you activities in TabHost.
3. Google has a fragment demo application for how to use fragment.

Comment: May i know where to get the demo ?